# Setting Path Directory on File Reader

Tags: java, file-io

I'm working with text files on Java. On Ubuntu 10.
But, I'm having problems with path dir.

Example:

`saveFile("textFile.txt","abc");`

This abstract function basically put "abc" on "textFile.txt".

I compile this file, and create a jar file (using NetBeans).
When I run the app, and call `saveFile("textFile.txt","abc")`, `textFile.txt` is saved on \home. I don't want this. I want that `textFile.txt`go to `pathDir` inside jar file.

**How do I write in this file, this same way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading resources from a JAR file, you cannot use the `File` API. Instead, you use `Class.getResourceAsStream()`, like this:

```
reader = new InputStreamReader(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(
    "/apathdir/textFile.txt"), "UTF-8");
```

Note also how the encoding is specified. `FileReader` does not allow that, which is why it should usually be avoided.

Comment: I'd like to know how do i write in this file, this same way?

Comment: @Richard: you generally cannot write to the JAR file your program is loaded from since it's locked by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

> Iwant to know, if fileName =
>   "textFile.txt", what is the path dir
>   of this file?

If you only use a bare file name (without giving a directory), the JVM will look for the file in the current directory of the JVM process; that is usually the directory you ran the JVM (the java executable) from.

> how do i do to set
>   /apathdir/textFile.txt?. apathdir is a
>   directory that is inside jar file.
>   I tried: fileName = "/apathdir/textFile.txt", but doesn't works.

If you want to load a file from inside a JAR file, you cannot load it using `FileReader`. You need to use `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream()` (or `Class.getResourceAsStream`). See e.g. this article for an explanation:

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5697